# jquery-ui.min.js takes too much time to load

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, performance, jquery-ui

**jquery-ui.min.js** takes too much time as per google page speed insights. is there any solution to reduce this time and improve performance of my page?.... I have loaded it as defer still it is showing this much time and that's why performance score is going down.

It takes 1.36s as per google speed test. see here:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide more details about your page and your issue. Right now, the question is too open ended and there is not enough detail to answer your question.

Comment: I am trying to speed up performance of our website and i did it according to google page speed. included very less js and css files and preloaded css files and used async and defer for js loading but i can't load this jquery-ui.min.js as async or defer as i am using it for autocomplete. so it is taking 1.36s to load which is reducing performance of page in our website. so is there any way to reduce this time as i need to increase the performance of our page?

Comment: There is not a way to really do that with the whole library. You can roll your own at https://jqueryui.com/download/ Here you can download just the parts of it that you need in a single js.min file and host that versus the entire library. This will reduce the size and thus the load time. Quck Link: https://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.12.1&components=110000010001000000100000100000000000000000000000

Comment: Thanks Twisty. I already tried for this but it giving some server error in downloading.

Comment: *If you're having trouble downloading a custom package or theme, please report the issue on GitHub.* https://github.com/jquery/download.jqueryui.com/issues